# Connecting two routers to a single modem - going crazy figuring it out

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I realize that this issue has been written about a billion times. But it is also true that there are a billion recipes on how to do it, which is why I'm confused.

I have two Linksys wrt1900ac routers. I want each router to have ITS OWN SEPARATE network and no files are shared.

Router #1: WAN port connected to the modem. It's running Gargoyle. LAN address: **192.168.1.1**  netmask: 255.255.255.0   DHCP: 100-150

ip addr output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GbNtgGbr86-KSnKfVLGDv5eB_4lcYaHSeSP7ewrr2Q8/edit?usp=sharing

Router #2: WAN port connected to one of the LAN ports of Router #1.
LAN IP Address:**192.168.2.1**
LAN Netmask:255.255.255.0
DHCP: 100-249

This setup worked for a while, although on and off I got disconnections on the second router, especially on 2.4 ghz.

Yesterday, I replaced Router #2's Linksys firmware with Gargoyle and now it has NO internet access, although all the settings are same as before.

Also when I use a Netgear router as the second router, still no internet access.

(situation changed as explained in comments. Now I have access son Router #2 only when set to DHCP Wireless, but not DHCP Wired. )

But when I connect the LAN cable coming for Router #1 to laptop, there is internet access.

I have read and read. Some articles say the DHCP range should not match. Or the wireless should be set to separate channels. But the IP's are totally different. One router is 192.168.1.1 and the other is 192.168.2.1

Others say the second router should have a static IP. Not sure how to do that or if it matters.

I think there is something fundamental I don't understand but can't figure it out.

Comment: *"I have two ... routers"* -- You have two WiFI routers.  *"This setup worked ... although ... I got disconnections on the second router, ..."* --You seem to conflate network configuration/issues with WiFi config/issues.  Those disconnections could be RF reception issues.  If you test with (wired) Ethernet connections, you can verify the network configuration of the routers (i.e. DHCP, NAT, firewall).  Only after that is working do you configure the WiFI, i.e. SSID, passphrase, RF channel, power levels.

Comment: If you really want both routers' networks to be completely separate, you can't have one cascaded off the other like you do right now. Because if you do that, devices on router 2 will be able to reach devices on router 1 (they won't be able to browse for services, but they would be able to ping addresses in 192.168.1.x/24 until they find hosts that respond, and then they'd be able to test ports on those IP addresses until they find services.

Answer (score 1):

> But it is also true that there are a billion recipes on how to do it, which is why I'm confused.

Don't blindly follow recipes. Read up on networking basics, understand *why* things need to be in a certain way, and understand your options.

> I want each router to have ITS OWN SEPARATE network

Routers don't "have networks". Most home routers are configured by default to act as DHCP server for a LAN/WLAN segment, but in general, routers route, which means they can connect multiple LAN segments.

> and no files are shared.

Routers don't "share files".

> WAN port connected to the modem.

So what does the modem do? Does it run its own DHCP service?

Possible network diagram (note that you draw **LAN segments** as primitives, not "routers"):

```
 192.168.1.*/24         ??.??.??.??/??            192.168.2.*/24
      |                        |                        |
      |  +-----------------+   |                        |
      +--|- 192.168.1.1    |   |   +-----------------+  |
      |  | LAN             |   |   |     192.168.2.1 |--+
      |  | WLAN   ?.?.?.? -|---+   |             LAN |  |
      |  |            WAN  |   +---| ?.?.?.?    WLAN |  |
      |  +-----------------+   |   | WAN             |  |
      |                        |   +-----------------+  |
      |                        |                        |
```

So you need to find out if

- your modem runs a DHCP server and provides addresses to both routers
- both your routers run a DHCP client on WAN and get addresses properly
- which address range your modem gives out (it can't be the same that the routers give out)
- both routers do NAT on WAN

You do that for example by using `ssh` to connect to the router, assuming it does run a firmware like OpenWRT where you can do that, and then you inspect the network configuration. If you don't have that, you're left with guessing at what the UI options your firmware gives you actually do.

Wildly speculating at what's going on isn't going to repair it.

**Edit**

I am sorry, but without any OS where you can actually figure out what is going on, and wild tries connecting up things to each other, and hoping to make it work, without actually describing what the settings used are, I am not able to debug this problem.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, thanks for your response. My modem is a ARRIS CM8200 DOCSIS 3.1 Modem. It is not a modem/router combo. Set me straight if I'm wrong, but I thought routers run DHCP not modems and don't give out an address range.  On the other items, would a print out of network config help?

Comment: I figured out SSH access to Openwrt running Router#1. Please let me know what output would help and if you know, give me the command. I'm newbie to command prompt

Comment: Please do `ip addr` when it's connected to the modem, upload output somewhere (pastebin etc.), and edit question with link. By default, routers expect to get a DHCP address on the WAN port. Yes, some modems work differently, but then you need to configure that in the router (and you haven't mentioned that).

Comment: Hi @dirkt, Here's the ip addr of Router #1   Comments section says it's too characters, so put here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GbNtgGbr86-KSnKfVLGDv5eB_4lcYaHSeSP7ewrr2Q8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here's what has changed since last time: I switched from Openwrt to Gargoyle on Router #1, taking care to tell it use fresh settings. So now both routers are now running Gargoyle. Openwrt just drove me nuts trying to figure out.  Now here's what the performance has changed: I have Internet access on Router #2, but only if it is connected to Router #1 via DHCP Wireless. scrn shot: https://nimb.ws/PsfIhU   If it is set to DHCP Wired, then there is no Internet access: https://nimb.ws/r3vTmV

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the cable connecting WAN of Router #1 to a LAN socket of Router #2. It has internet access when I connect it to a laptop.   Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is nutty but Router #2 lost internet access and stopped broadcasting wireless half an hour after I posted previous comment. It was set to DHCP Wireless, which was working fine earlier. Then after a while it started broadcasting 5ghz SSID and 5ghz guest SSID. But still no internet access and no broadcast of 2ghz SSID's.  Does this indicate hardware issue? Router is broken? turning off and turning back on the router did not change anything. Did same thing on occasion when it was running Linksys firmware (before changing to Gargoyle). Broadcasts stopped once in a while, particularly 2ghz.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link, but it requires a Google account to use, so, not going to be able to read this. The next step would have been to figure out if the IP you got is from the modem or from your ISP, and use a switch (or re-configure one of your routers to be a switch, or re-configure the OpenWRT router to use one LAN port as a second bridged WAN port) in the former case to get an IP to both routers. Can't do any of this with Gargoyle, so you need to figure it out yourself.